# Capture a html node's content as a video stream

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

I have a weird requirement where I need to capture an svg element as a video stream. Basically it's a drawing app and as the user draws with a pen the drawing is displayed as an svg element. I need to record a video of it kind of like how a screen recorder would work except only the div containing the svg element should be recorded. What are my options? How can I achieve this ? Another important thing is that the entire recording should be available on the server with out failure or with as little loss as possible.

Comment: Although, it's not impossible, it will be very heavy on the memory. Basically, what you'll need to do is convert the entire SVG in which you draw in into an image. This image will represent a single frame. The image should then be drawn into a canvas, which is able to create a stream. The stream should then be recorded using a `MediaRecorder` instance which in turn takes the stream and converts it into a video. But the catch is that you have to create so many images for each frame out of your SVG that, unless you're clever, will clog up memory.

Comment: The would be way easier to just use the canvas to draw on and capture the stream. It will save you many steps and will be more performant. What are your options?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier what if I send svg data along with timestamps over websocket and simulate it using puppeteer js on the server and somehow record it? Because transferring a video file generated by media recorder api sounds like a lot of data to upload to server and bandwidth is a constrain on the client side. Not to mention the requirement that recording should be available on the server with very less failure rate and uploading a large video file from client browser is not optimal as users will most definitely terminate the upload.

Comment: Creating a video on the frontend would be the same as on the backend. The thing is that you have to take pictures of each frame of SVG and then record every picture resulting in double the amount of data. It totally depends on how long the user is painting. But if bandwidth is a constraint, then the currently used methods could be problematic. But hey, you won't really know unless you've tried it.

Comment: The WebSockets proposal seems interesting, though. It might lift some weight of from the frontend, but it might not guarantee a steady framerate, because data will be sent after conversion of the SVG element. And the more complex, the longer it might take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of thought I went with this solution:

1. Install xvfb and chromium and ffmpeg on a linux container
2. Server a webpage from another container
3. Launch chromium with xvfb and navigate a the url that simulates user actions.
   I wrote a custom webpage that does that.
4. Use puppetter to run a specific function on the webpage and then record using ffmpeg.
5. After the async task is completed send a SIGINT to ffmpeg and terminate it
6. Done.

There is obviously a lot of code ( several hundreds of lines ) for me to post here and even if I could it's for a client and I can't disclose the source code. But these are the steps I followed.